# Ссылки в меню мобильной версии сайта не кликабельны

Tags: html, css, ссылки, menu, меню

Всем привет. Подскажите пожалуйста, как заставить ссылки в меню мобильной версии сайта работать? Ссылки стали не кликабельны. Меню без js, только html и css. Сайт: https://vizualika.ru

Comment: Для получения корректного ответа Вам стоит конкретизировать вопрос, добавив в него необходимую информацию. Справа от формы создания вопроса есть рекомендации. Также рекомендую ознакомиться со статьей [Как задать хороший вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы в стилях к этим элементам отменили [события мыши](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events), таким образом клики не обрабатываются и не переводят Вас по ссылкам.

```
header nav a:nth-child(1) {
    color: #cccccc;
    text-decoration: underline;
    pointer-events: none; - тут должно быть auto. А лучше вовсе удалите этот стиль
}
```

Comment: Любезнейший, как же я вам благодарен! Весь файл стилей перерыл, а про встроенный забыл. Этот стиль задавал для меню десктопной версии, но id указать не догадался. Тысячу раз спасибо!